# Extract tweets and write to Postgres using Akka

Tags: scala, twitter, akka, slick

I want to create an application using which it would be possible to extract tweets by specified hashtag, write them to the database (Postgres) and then using slick get this data by sending requests to API. For that, I want to use Akka Streaming, HTTP, Slick. I only saw some examples of Twitter Client usage with no writes to the database but the direct usage of tweets fields through Akka streaming, like [this guide](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC2/scala/stream-quickstart.html#stream-quickstart-scala).

So is that possible to extract these tweets using Twitter Search API or any other API and write them to a database directly?

Comment: In the simplest case you can write a function `def writeOneTweetToDB(tweet: Tweet): Future[Result]`. Given a stream of tweets as a source, you can then use `.mapAsync(1)(writeOneTweetToDB)` to write tweets to the DB one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use Slick database publisher. Database publishers can be used as a Source in any akka streaming application

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/dbio.html#streaming

Comment: I don't really understand how I can apply this to my case. I mean, should I use database publisher to write already extracted data? but how can I extract the data or better to say in which format to write it easier into the database?

Comment: Yes you can read existing data by creating an Akka Source from the Slick database publisher. Look at the example in the link i gave you.

Comment: The question seems to be about writing to the database though.